# How to make Keras automatically load custom metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, root-framework

I'm using Keras with Cern ROOT and its analysis package TMVA. The way it works is that I use Keras to initialize the NN, then save it to a file, then TMVA loads that file in. The problem is that I am using custom metrics when setting up the neural network, and when doing this, Keras wants you to do something like

```
    models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects={"my_object":my_object})
```

Unfortunately, the way that TMVA takes arguments requires that I only supply the filename of the model file being used. However, based on the error messages that I am getting, it is clear that it is simply using Keras to load the model in. My question  is, how do I force Keras to automatically load my custom objects in without having to use the above line, as this is incompatible with the package I'm trying to use.

Comment: there is no way to couple the metrics with the keras object while saving. Without modifying TMVA, I do not believe you could couple your custom metrics.

Comment: @modesitt that's what I figured, seems to be a fairly common issue. Any way I could not include the metric in the model itself but have ModelCheckpoint evaluate and print them at each epoch?